# Finding the equation of a curve where the gradient is $ax + b$ at all points.

Tags: integration, curves

The gradient of a curve is $ax + b$ at all points, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Find the equation of the curve given that it passes through the points $(0,4)$ and $(1,3)$ and that the tangent at $(1,3)$ is parallel to the $x$-axis.

My workings so far are:

$\int ax + b$ $dx$ $= \frac{ax^2}{2} + bx + c$

for $(0,4)$:

$ 4 = \frac{a * (0^2)}{2} + b * 0 + c $

$ 4 = 0+c $

therefore $ c = 4 $

making the equation $\frac{ax^2}{2} + bx + 4$

for $(1,3)$:

$3 = \frac{a*(1^2)}{2} + b*1 + 4 $

$3 = \frac{a}{2} + b + 4$

The answer given is $y = x^2 - 2x + 4$

So I feel like I've got most of the way there, I'm just stuck on where to go next e.g. finding the values for $a$ and $b$, so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You have a second condition for the tangent. Use that in the curve that you found out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the tangent line at $(1,3)$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, meaning that the gradient when $x=3$ is $0.$

On the other hand, we know that the gradient is always of the form $ax+b$ at any given $x.$ In particular, the gradient when $x=3$ is $3a+b.$

Now you have *two* linear equations with variables $a$ and $b,$ which will let you finish the problem.

Comment: Didn't put that in, I know that when $x = 3$ the gradient is $0$

Comment: So, what does that tell you about $3a+b$?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Well, you know that $ax+b=0$ when $x=3,$ and so....